# RabbitMQ exchange (direct, topic) to have a default queue

Tags: rabbitmq

Is it possible to have some "default" queue for a rabbitmq exchange with a type 'direct'?

Like, i have an exchange A and queues Q1,Q2,Q3,QDef . so if somethign is published with routing key Q1. it will go to to Q1. 
But if a message is with a routing key Q4 then it should go to QDef.
If routing key is not name of existent queue then a message should go to QDef.

Is it possible to do with a rabbitmq? Maybe exchange should not be of a type 'direct' but some other type?

With other words.
If some consumer declared a queue for some routing key then messages should go to this queue. If not then messages should go to a default consumer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can obtain the intended behavior by using and [alternate exchange](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ae.html) (AE).

So you should define the AE for you exchange A  and bind your queue QDef  to it. *Unroutable* messages will be delivered to it.